# Program that updates the current time by one second

Tags: c

I am working through Kochan's Programming in C. This is exercise 9-5. 
The program increments the time by one second. The code compiles fine, but the time does not update as expected. When I replace the code in the timeUpdate function with

```
printf("Test");
```

it prints "Test", so it doesn't seem like there are problems with calling the function. However, when I replace the code with

```
now.seconds = 2;
```

or something, the seconds isn't updated to 2. Please help me debug my code. I apologize if I'm making really obvious mistakes. I am, unfortunately, a really fresh beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dateAndTime
{
    int days;
        int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

// Updates the time by one second
struct dateAndTime timeUpdate(struct dateAndTime now)
{   
    now.seconds++; 
    if (now.seconds == 60) // One minute
    {
        now.seconds = 0; 
        now.minutes++; 
        if (now.minutes == 60) // One hour
        {
            now.minutes = 0;
            now.hours++; 
        }
    }


    return now; 
}


// Increments days by one when hours reaches 24
struct dateAndTime dateUpdate(struct dateAndTime now)
{
    now.days++;
    now.hours = 0; 
    return now; 
}

// Calls timeUpdate to increment time by one second
struct dateAndTime clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime now)
{
    timeUpdate(now); 

    // If hours reaches 24, increments dys by one
    if (now.hours == 24)
    {
        dateUpdate(now); 
    }

    return now; 
}

int main(void)
{
    struct dateAndTime clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime now); 
    struct dateAndTime present, future; 

    // Prompts and accepts user input
    printf("Enter a time (dd:hh:mm:ss): "); 
    scanf("%i:%i:%i:%i", &present.days, &present.hours,
        &present.minutes, &present.seconds); 

    future = clockKeeper(present); 

    // Prints updated time
    printf("The updated time is: %.2i:%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", future.days, future.hours,
        future.minutes, future.seconds); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  IMNSHO, the three functions are not really a good design. Quite apart from passing by value vs passing by reference, having the `timeUpdate()` function leave the structure in an incoherent state (when the hour changes from 23 to 24) means it is not safe to use that function outside this module.  It should all be handled in a single function which ensures that when a time value is modified, the result is always consistent with the rules. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ I believe the rules are such that the assertion `assert(now.seconds >= 0 && now.seconds < 60 && now.minutes >= 0 && now.minutes < 60 && now.hours >= 0 && now.hours < 24 && now.days >= 0);` should never fail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page might be better than the help center.

Comment: I wrote square bracket, FAQ, square bracket; the powers-that-be have mapped that to Help Centre (only they misspelled centre, of course).  I'm not sure I like the change, but ...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Could you tell me a case in which the function might fail?

Comment: And, out of curiosity, why am I being downvoted? Did I break a rule? :(

Comment: I see no rule broken.  I have noticed that having a "question", which yours post lacks, clearly stated, elicits more positive responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you pass the structure *by value* and return it *by value* in all the functions. Therefore in `clockKeeper` when you call `timeUpdate` you pass a *copy* that will be modified, but you don't actually update the copy local to `clockKeeper`.

Every time you do a call you have to remember to assign it back to itself, e.g.:

```
struct dateAndTime clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime now)
{
    now = timeUpdate(now); 
    // Note assignment back to `now`

    // If hours reaches 24, increments dys by one
    if (now.hours == 24)
    {
        now = dateUpdate(now); 
        // Note assignment back to `now`
    }

    return now; 
}
```

---

Or you can pass the structure *by reference*, by using pointers to the structure.

Like this:

```
struct dateAndTime *dateUpdate(struct dateAndTime *now)
{
    now->days++;
    now->hours = 0; 
    return now; 
}
```

Then you have to change all function to receive pointers, and you can discard the return value.